# ITMS-90892: Missing recommended icon error from Apple App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I get this error when submitting my app to the App Store recently.

> ITMS-90892: Missing recommended icon - The bundle does not contain an alternate app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See

It's related to the alternate icons in the app structure and the names I think but has nothing to do with the assets catalog. In my app a user can choose and icon for the Home Screen.

I have 4 icons to choose and 4 sizes for each icon named e.g. - AA_appIcon@2x, AA_appIcon@2x~iPad, AA_appIcon@3x, AA_appIcon83.5@2x~iPad and it used to work fine, but now I get this error for the one name AA_appIcon83.5@2x~iPad.
It is in the correct size 167x167, so not sure what the problem is.
It just happen in the last few days, didn't happen on my previous submission a month ago.

The naming format must have recently changed or something.
Is anyone able to spot the error?

This is the info.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>AA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Cake</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Cake_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>NA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>OA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>OA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Cake_appIcon</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>AA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Cake</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Cake_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>NA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <key>OA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>OA_appIcon</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Cake_appIcon</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's what you need as of late 2021 if you're getting error `ITMS-90890` or `ITMS-90892`, etc.

| File Name | size |
| --- | --- |
| IconName@2x.png | 120x120 |
| IconName@3x.png | 180x180 |
| IconName@2x~ipad.png | 152x152 |
| IconName@3x~ipad.png | 167x167 |

*Note the lack of capitalization on `~ipad`!

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Warpling answer, here is everything you need to setup alternate icon correctly:

### 1. Create the icon files

First, you'll have to create a folder (e.g. `AlternateAppIcons`) inside your main project (where the `info.plist` file is located).

Now, inside the folder you've created, add the files with the names and sizes that described in the table:

| File Name | Size |
| --- | --- |
| IconName@2x.png | 120x120 |
| IconName@3x.png | 180x180 |
|  |  |
| IconName@2x~ipad.png | 152x152 |
| IconName@3x~ipad.png | 167x167 |

- I'd recommend you to use [Icon Set Creator](https://apps.apple.com/il/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?l=iw&mt=12) to generate all sizes, then
- Make sure that the file names are exactly the same (case sensitive) after the @.
- When you change `IconName`, make sure to change it as well in the `info.plist`.

### 2. Configure `info.plist`

You'll have to add this to the `info.plist`:

```xml
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IconName</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>IconName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAlternateIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IconName</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>IconName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

### 3. Change the icon programmatically

All you have to do is to validate that the app supports alternate icons and change it:

```swift
guard UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons else { return }
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("IconName")
```

*You may want to create some `enum` helper like [this](https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-add-alternative-app-icons-for-ios/#asset-catalog).

## SwiftUI

Since SwiftUI [drops the requirement of info.plist](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-missing-info.plist/), you'll have to make the declaration in a different way; search for "App Icon" in the project's `Build Settings` to edit the related settings.

You may take a look at [Apple's new documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring_your_app_to_use_alternate_app_icons), that includes also a [sample project](https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/ba6fbde5c8/ConfiguringYourAppToUseAlternateAppIcons.zip) (take a look at its `README.md`).

You may also find [this article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/alternate-app-icon-configuration-in-xcode/) helpful.

Comment: Is there no need to add reference to the path of the images inside `AlternateAppIcons`? because the `AlternateAppIcons` Path it is not shown in the `info.plist`

Comment: @kike No, the default path is the `AlternateAppIcons` folder, it isn’t just a name I’ve chosen, it’s a name that recognized by the system.

Comment: I have just tested under iIOS16 (and SDK from latest Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b) ) just a note:    a) folder name is NOT important (I used another name)       b) you simply have to behave as 10 years ago with old icons ;(

Comment: @ingconti Thank you for the information. a) I've updated the answer to just suggest this name. b) you're probably right, but myself and a lot of other people weren't able to find good answer that explains in it about the *whole* process, so I've gathered a few answers that helped me into one helpful answer.

Comment: @ido: you are right! by the way it works fine in debug via USB, but seems we have to further investigate for Apple Store..

Comment: This is not working, Apple rejects the app with this approach

Comment: @ArtemGolendukhin What is the exact message that you are getting with the rejection? Since when it started?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind

I just renamed the icon from `AA_appIcon83.5@2x~iPad.png` to `AA_appIcon@3x~ipad.png` and the error went away and the icon picker still works from within the app.